# China puts Xi’s name in constitution. do you know a similar case?

Tags: constitution, china, international

[China puts Xi’s name in constitution](http://www.presstv.com/Detail/2017/10/25/539800/China-President-Xi-Jinping-Communist-Party-Standing). It is strange (for me) to put a politician name in constitution (specially when the politician is not the founder of that Gov.)
do you know a similar case in the other countries?

Comment: iirc, Deng Xiaoping had his name in constitution ealrier

Comment: I don't think it's Xi's name, but Xi's theory's name. When I was in school I knew Marx/Lenin/Mao/Deng's theories were all listed as guiding theories in the constitution, I am pretty sure they added each for each leader after Deng. Xi's is just another.

Comment: My understanding is that Xi's name was added to the [Constitution of the Chinese Communist Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_Communist_Party_of_China), not to the [Constitution of China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_China) itself.  These are two separate things.

Comment: I'm getting an error from the link in the question. Could you copy the relevant passage here?

Answer (score 10):

[Atatürk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustafa_Kemal_Atat%C3%BCrk) is mentioned in the preamble to [Turkey's 1961 Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_Constitution_of_1961).

> ...and with full dedication to the spirit of National independence,
>   and sovereignty and to the reforms of Atatürk;

([English translation](http://www.anayasa.gen.tr/1961constitution-text.pdf), not the original Turkish)

The modern 1982 constitution that replaced it expanded his reference to:

> ...in line with the concept of nationalism introduced by
>   the founder of the Republic of Turkey, Atatürk, the immortal leader
>   and the unrivalled hero, and his reforms and principles;

Atatürk was not the founder of either government, but he was effectively the father of the modern state of Turkey.

Answer (score 8):

The first line of the North Korean Constitution, translated:

> The Democratic People`s Republic of Korea is a self-reliant socialist state that has realized the ideas and leadership of Kim Il Sung. [(source)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_North_Korea_(1972,_rev._1998))

Constitution of CCCP mentions to Lenin, and later discusses "Marxism-Leninism":

> The Great October Socialist Revolution, made by the workers and peasants of Russia under the leadership of the Communist Party headed by Lenin, overthrew capitalist and landowner rule, broke the fetters of oppression, ...

Several other constitutions mention "Marx", or at least "Marxism". I expect there are constitutions that mention the names of religious leaders, such as Jesus or Mohammed.

Comment: thanks. question edited; I mean the name of Contemporary era
politicians. so the case of  prophet Jesus or prophet  Mohammed, Peace be upon them, is not what i mean.

Answer (score 5):

- At least one country's constitution mentions Simón Bolívar ([Venezuela's](https://venezuelanalysis.com/constitution/title/1)).

  > Article 1: The **Bolivarian** Republic of Venezuela ...
- As JamesK alluded to, [Iran's](http://www.wipo.int/edocs/lexdocs/laws/en/ir/ir001en.pdf) (at least) constitution mentions Propher Mohammed, in preamble:

  > *Representatives*
  >   The Council of Experts, consisting of the representatives of the people, ...
  >   The constitution, which consists of twelve chapters, and 175 articles, is completed in accordance with the aforementioned motives and objectives, at the dawn of the fifteenth century, **after the migration of the Noble Prophet
  >   (Peace and blessing be upon him and his family) the founder of the liberating ideology of Islam**.

  As well in actual articles:

  > *Chapter 2: The Language, Script, Calendar, and the Official Flag of the Country*
  >   Article 17: The official calendar of the country is based on the date of the **migration (622 CE) of the Prophet of Islam (God’s peace be upon him and his family)**.

  Of course, it also mentions Muslim deity (Allah), in line #1:

  > In the Name of Allah, Most Gracious, Most Merciful

  and

  > **In the Name of the Almighty God**
  >   The Constitution of the Islamic Republic of Iran
  >   Chapter 1: General Principles

Comment: thanks. question edited; I mean the name of Contemporary era
politicians. so the case of  prophet Jesus or prophet  Mohammed, Peace be upon them, is not what i mean.

Comment: I know Bolivar would be somewhere, well found.

Comment: I'm tempted to argue the first is merely using a real person's name as an adjective (like [Quisling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quisling)). However, in this case I think its really just a matter of degree compared to the two examples I put up (which used whole phrases containing the guy's name as adjectives). So +1

Answer (score 1):

[Cuba's constitution](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Cuba_2019.pdf?lang=en) was revised in 2019 by referendum to add Fidel Castro's name to that of José Martí's in the preamble:

> GUIDED
> by the most advanced revolutionary, anti-imperialist, Cuban-Marxist,
> Latin American, and universal thought, in particular by the ideal and
> example of Martí and **Fidel**, as well as the social emancipation ideas
> of Marx, Engels, and Lenin;
>
> SUPPORTED
> in proletariat internationalism, fraternal friendship, the help,
> cooperation, and solidarity of the peoples of the world, particularly
> those of Latin America and the Caribbean;
>
> ...
>
> IDENTIFIED
> with the tenets displayed in the concept of Revolution, as
> expressed by the **Commander in Chief Fidel Castro** on the 1st of May of
> the year 2000;

On a slightly different note, [Libya's constitution](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/Libya_2012.pdf?lang=en) adopted after the fall of Muammar Gaddafi in 2011 notes his part in the country's history:

> Believing in the Revolution of 17th of February, 2011 (14th Rabi’
> El-Awal, 1432 Hijri), lead by the Libyan people in the different
> regions of the country, and being faithful to the martyrs of this
> blessed revolution who sacrificed their lives to obtain freedom, live
> in dignity in the territory of their country and recover their rights
> derided by **Kadhafi and his fallen regime**;

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you're asking about, but it's not totally unrelated, so I thought I'd mention it.

The [22nd Amendment to the US Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty-second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) includes the text:

> But this Article shall not apply to any person holding the office of President when this Article was proposed by the Congress

It's not by name, but technically that is a constitutional provision referring only to a single contemporary politician: Harry Truman.